# PHP calling method does not run it, it just stays loading

Tags: php

I am trying to call a method from another file, but when the code gets to that line it just stays loading, does not move on, and the function does not return anything. I have the function that uses an `array` and the connection parameters, and I call it from other php.

The function .php :

```
class OperatiiBD
{

//getting a specified token to send push to selected device
public function getTokenByEmail($email){
            require_once 'conn.php';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT token_notificare FROM informatii_persoane WHERE adresa_mail = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    return $result['token_notificare'];        
}
public function getEmailById($array_utiliz, $conn){
    $max = count($array_utiliz);
    $i=0;
    while($i < $max){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT adresa_mail FROM informatii_persoane WHERE id_utilizator = ?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$array_utiliz[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    $array_adrese_mail[]=$result;
    }
    return $array_adrese_mail;        
}
}
```

The way I call it:

```
require_once 'OperatiiBD.php';
$db = new OperatiiBD();             
echo $db->getEmailById($utilizatori_notificari, $conn);
```

I have checked and the `$utilizatori_notificari` returns [79,34,109], exactly the desired output.

Comment: When I added `require_once 'conn.php';` , it gave me an error, that `conn` was undefined.

Comment: @Costin because its so bad, really bad, read about OOP.. everything is wrong here

Comment: It seems that you did not update `$i` in your `while` loop. So it's loop forever.

Comment: Change `require_once 'conn.php';` to `GLOBAL $conn;` in class and call class like this `$db = new OperatiiBD($conn);`

Comment: @GrenierJ indeed i forgot about `$i`. Now the issue it's `Notice: Array to string conversion` from the line `echo $db->getEmailById($utilizatori_notificari, $conn);`

Comment: @Costin because you can echo only string!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Classic and simple solution of creating a class would be like follows no need to include `OperatiiBD.php`

```
class OperatiiBD {
    protected $conn;

    function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function getTokenByEmail($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT token_notificare FROM informatii_persoane WHERE adresa_mail = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $result['token_notificare'];
    }
}
```

Calling class (Usaqe):

```
require_once 'OperatiiBD.php';
$YouCls = new OperatiiBD($conn);
$user = $YouCls->getTokenByEmail($_POST['email']);
```